# Process stops without creating core dump on OpenVZ Container

Tags: linux-kernel, coredump, openvz

I am running a process (a service) in a container. After few mins the process stops (or a crash) but there is no core dump generated.

When I try to intentionally create a core dump (for E.g: dividing 10/0 in my program) it creates a core dump.

But the same process(without intentional crash) will stop and does not create core dump.

What could be the problem?

Here are more specific details of my kernel on a VPS:

```
[root@test101 ~]# sysctl -a |egrep -i "core"
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
kernel.core_pattern = core.%e.%p
kernel.core_pipe_limit = 4
net.core.somaxconn = 128
net.core.xfrm_aevent_etime = 10
net.core.xfrm_aevent_rseqth = 2
net.core.xfrm_larval_drop = 1
net.core.xfrm_acq_expires = 30
net.core.wmem_max = 131071
net.core.rmem_max = 131071
net.core.wmem_default = 133120
net.core.rmem_default = 133120
net.core.dev_weight = 64
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 1000
net.core.message_cost = 5
net.core.message_burst = 10
net.core.optmem_max = 20480
net.core.rps_sock_flow_entries = 0
net.core.netdev_budget = 300
net.core.warnings = 1

[root@test101 ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 8041
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: How did you make sure that your program indeed crashed/terminated abnormally? It could have terminated normally?

Comment: It is a daemon running in a infinite loop and I am pretty sure it has not exited normally unless I ask it to do so. :-) and this happens only in OpenVZ environment.

Comment: Its very difficult to predict anything without the actual code. Can you paste your code? If its permitted?

Comment: why dont you run it through a debugger? Debuggers can catch SISSEGV and other signals too

Answer (score 0):

add following lines to your /etc/security/limits.conf:

- soft    core          unlimited
- hard    core          unlimited
  root            soft    core          unlimited
  root            hard    core          unlimited